# What would could cause a discord.py-task.loop to keep running every second even though I specify for it to run every 2 minutes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I added a task.loop into my discord bot to back up data to gdrive. In the code below you can see that I specified for it to run every 2 minutes in the flag. But when I run it, i'll see it print to console every second then slow down to 4-5 seconds after 3-4 print statements. Did I miss any steps in my code that would cause this issue?

```py
import discord
import discord.utils
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import shutil
import os
from pathlib import Path
import time

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    # Authenticate if they're not there
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    # Refresh them if expired
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    # Initialize the saved creds
    gauth.Authorize()
# Save the current credentials to a file
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.reactions = True
intents.messages = True
intents.emojis = True

with open("token.txt", 'r') as token_reader:
    TOKEN = token_reader.readlines()
    TOKEN = TOKEN[0]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents = intents)
client.remove_command('help')

class Main:
    def  __init__(self,TOKEN,client):
        self.token = TOKEN
        self.client  = client
        self.files = []

    def onStartup(self):
        self.backups.start()
        self.client.run(self.token)

    @tasks.loop(seconds=0, minutes=2.0, hours=0, count=None)
    async def backups(self):
        print('test')

        shutil.copy("scripts/battleplan.txt",Path().absolute())
        shutil.copy("scripts/rolesMSG.txt",Path().absolute())
        os.remove("scripts/battleplan.txt")
        os.remove("scripts/rolesMSG.txt")

        save = ["battleplan.txt", "discordBot","rolesMSG.txt"]
        self.files = sorted(self.files, key = lambda x: x['title'])
        for i, file in enumerate(self.files):
            print('uploading {} file from GDrive ({}/{})'.format(file['title'], i, len(self.files)-1))
            file.SetContentFile(save[i])
            file.Upload()
            #print("hit")

        shutil.copy("battleplan.txt","scripts")
        shutil.copy("rolesMSG.txt","scripts")
        os.remove("battleplan.txt")
        os.remove("rolesMSG.txt")

    @backups.before_loop
    async def before_backups(self):
        print('waiting...')
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()


main = Main(TOKEN,client)

@main.client.event  # event decorator/wrapper
async def on_ready():

    await main.client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name = 'Type ''$help'' for a list of commands!'))
    print(f"We have logged in as {main.client.user}")


    file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false".format('ID goes here')}).GetList()

    for i, file in enumerate(sorted(file_list, key = lambda x: x['title']), start=1):
        print('Downloading {} file from GDrive ({}/{})'.format(file['title'], i, len(file_list)))
        file.GetContentFile(file['title'])
    shutil.copy("battleplan.txt","scripts")
    shutil.copy("rolesMSG.txt","scripts")
    os.remove("battleplan.txt")
    os.remove("rolesMSG.txt")

    main.files = file_list

main.onStartup()
```

EDIT: updated code to reflect what im currently working with. Line 60 where I use save = [] and start my for loop is the issue, I independently verified that this is what is causing the loop to run again

EDIT 2: the line "file.SetContentFile(save[i])" is the problem. is it because im accessing the variable through global scope?

EDIT 3: its not because of global scope, just changed it to save the files in the class (edited the code in this answer to reflect this) and also verified that the sort method wasnt the cause either. its still "file.SetContentFile(save[i])" that is the issue.

EDIT 4: I was able to fix the issue with by simplifying and correcting the problimatic .SetContentFile function:

```
    @tasks.loop(minutes=30)
    async def backups(self):
        print("----------------Backing up files----------------")

        self.files = sorted(self.files, key = lambda x: x['title'])
        for i, file in enumerate(self.files):
            print('Uploading {} file from GDrive ({}/{})'.format(file['title'], i+1, len(self.files)))
            file.SetContentFile(os.path.join('scripts', file['title']))
            file.Upload()
```

It seems like if there is an error in your code, discord.py will spam the loop instead of allowing the error to continue, then it retries to do the loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're only intended to specify one of `seconds`/`minutes`/`hours`. The documentation doesn't make this clear, though. Assuming the answer below is correct, I would encourage you to take the matter to the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues) and ask for clearer documentation.

Comment: I thought so as well but found that in a stack overflow post trying to get it to work as intended. Ill look at the page and see what happens

Comment: @KarlKnechtel see my edit, I found  it was my for loop thats causing the issue but have no idea why

Comment: You're printing inside the for-loop.

Comment: thats not the problem, look at my edits and my answer, thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with by simplifying and correcting the problimatic .SetContentFile function:

```
    @tasks.loop(minutes=30)
    async def backups(self):
        print("----------------Backing up files----------------")

        self.files = sorted(self.files, key = lambda x: x['title'])
        for i, file in enumerate(self.files):
            print('Uploading {} file from GDrive ({}/{})'.format(file['title'], i+1, len(self.files)))
            file.SetContentFile(os.path.join('scripts', file['title']))
            file.Upload()
```

It seems like if there is an error in your code, discord.py will spam the loop instead of allowing the error to continue, then it retries to do the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting seconds to 120 and getting rid of the other args:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
```

Comment: Still doesnt work, tried seconds, hours, minutes, and it keeps spamming it

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?? I am seeing this now out of nowhere @CharlieWatson

Comment: @Chitowns24 I did actually, there was an issue with the line of code defined in edit #3, in the end tasks.loop(minutes=30) worked for me when I fixed that problematic line of code. To me at least, if there is an error with your code, it will just spam the loop instead of waiting.

Comment: So weird! It was silent too.. thanks!